# Perfom Voice synthetize when start Speech Recognition

Tags: windows, win-universal-app, performance-testing, voice-recognition

I have a trouble because when i run my program on a device (Lumia 830) my voice synthetizer freeze on some phrases.. I Make a lot of test and I discover the problem is when I initialize a speech recognition... I try to do a lot of thing like separe the code synthezis and recognize.. but it doesn't not work. Some one have an idea how to solve this problem? For example here when my phone says: "say a command" It's froozen in the final phrase like a Commmaaaaaaaaaaaand..: Its really a Headache

This is my code:

```
        sin.Voice = (SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(x => x.Gender == VoiceGender.Male));

        var language = new Windows.Globalization.Language("en-EN");

        SpeechRecognizer recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(language);



        List<string> dict= new List<string>();


        string[] responses = { "One", "Twoo", "three", "End", "Exit", };


        var listConstraint = new Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognitionListConstraint(responses, "Comandos");


        recognizer.Constraints.Add(listConstraint);
        await recognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync();

        var recognition = recognizer.RecognizeAsync();

        //await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High, new DispatchedHandler(
        //   () => { mediaElement.Stop(); mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType); mediaElement.Play(); }));
        texto = "     " + "    " + "Say a COmmand" + "     " + "    ";
        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await sin.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(texto);


        if (mediaElement.CurrentState.Equals(MediaElementState.Playing))
        {
            mediaElement.Stop();
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();

        }else
        {
            //mediaElement.Stop();
            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();

        }



        recognition.Completed += this.Recognition_Completed;
```

Comment: From the code it doesn't seem you want to run them separately. You can wait for synthesis first and start recognition only after that. Why do you start them in the same time.

Comment: YEs, its correct.. I try after them.. But I resolve this problem.. How?.. Run Separately both procedure.. but Including a Task Delay on 800 ms.. It works Great!! If you run both procedure with out delay the problem is present again... Is rare because on Emulator runs Well!!

Comment: Why aren't you awaiting the `RecognizeAsync`?